# How to change Devise's "from address" with a custom Mailer class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a Rails app that handles two domains. I therefore need to be able to specify as a variable which email address Devise should send confirmation emails from.

In `config/environments/development.rb` I have these settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'localhost',
    :user_name            => 'my_default_email@example.com',
    :password             => 'MyPassword',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I have created a custom Mailer as described in [this post](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer). My custom mailer now looks like this:

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:from]     = 'my_custom_email@example.com'
    opts[:reply_to] = 'my_custom_email@example.com'
    super
  end
end
```

The method does seem to be triggered, because my server log states this:

```
Sent mail to some_customer@example.com (4601.4ms)
Date: Sat, 23 Aug 2014 11:26:51 -0700
From: my_custom_email@example.com
Reply-To: my_custom_email@example.com
To: some_customer@example.com
```

However, in the customer inbox, the actual email states `my_default_email@example.com` as the from address and only states `my_custom_email@example.com` as reply-to address.

I suppose I should pass in more SMTP options for my custom email address, but how?

Comment: Can you look at the raw email in the inbox?  Is there any trace of `my_custom_email@example.com` in any of the mail headers?  Depending on what the email addresses actually are, I'm wondering if it's some sort of anti-spam measure (like gmail's 'via' or outlook's 'on behalf of', though it sounds like you're seeing something even less helpful than those!).

Comment: The only trace is the _respond to_ that points to `my_custom_email@example.com`. I am looking at the email in Gmail, but as far as I can see Gmail shouldn't even be aware of `my_default_email@example.com` if the application was doing things right. In addition I can point out, that if I entirely remove the smtp settings in `config/environments/development.rb`, the application doesn't send out any email.

Comment: Sorry it's been ages! Did you fix it? Gmail is aware of `my_default_email@example.com` because that's the `user_name` you're setting for accessing gmail's SMTP server, so I think everything is prob. fine in your rails app - you prob. have to let gmail send email on behalf of the other address by going into gmail and changing settings: Settings->Accounts and Import->Send mail as: and then 'Add another email address that you own'. The snag is it looks like you may need to use an external SMTP server if the other address isn't also a gmail address (or unless you're using Google Apps perhaps).